# Does the name of the target can use Reference properties?

Tags: msbuild

I want to include property names inside the target name.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Property1>Example</Property1>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="$(Property1)">
```

But i got an error: **error MSB5016: The
 name "$(Property1)" contains an invalid character "$".**

Does the name has to be hard-coded?